# Deploy project using git With (Respository with different folder estructure than local)

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm learning a bit about git and devops and I'm trying to deploy a a couple of scripts using azure devops pipelines.

The flow that i have in mind is something like:

Git trigger -> git pull command -> run a test command

In the repository I have this folder structure:

```
project
|
└───folder1
│       file111.txt
│       file112.txt
│       ...
│   
└───folder2
│       file111.txt
│       file112.txt
│       ...
│   
└───folder3
│       file111.txt
│       file112.txt
│       ...
```

However, for the deploy, The folder1 is part of 1 VM (this VM only gonna have this folder)
and the other 2 folders gonna be in another VM.

Finally, the folder3 needs to be into the folder2 in the VM.

The structure in the VM,s will be:

VM1:

```
folder1
│   file111.txt
│   file112.txt
```

VM2:

```
folder2
│   file011.txt
│   file012.txt
│   │
│   └───folder3
│       │   file111.txt
│       │   file112.txt
```

Any idea how i can du this using git? from your experience, this is the best approach to do this?

I'm thinking I can use the Copy file Task but I'm not sure if I can copy only the files added/modified in the repo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think git is really the relevant tool for this - unless your files are huge, don't worry about which are changed, just check out the revision somewhere, and then let the CI tool treat it as a bunch of directories to zip up and deploy to relevant places.

Comment: The best way to approach this is to use copyFiles task by checking out the repo on each VM and copy the relevant files/folders to the intended location. and If these folders where part of multiple different repositories then you could use resources: in your pipeline to achieve this but that is not necessary in your case since everything is part of the same repository and same project.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses, brought me a good overview of how to tackle this challenge!

Answer (score 2):

The build agent **working directory** is the folder you will use to accomplish your requirement. When you add your Azure pipeline .yml file on a github repository the source code will be downloaded automatically on the sourcesDirectory. The default working directory for devOps agents is `C:\agent\work`.

Your repository if you do not have multiple checkouts will be downloaded into `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/`

In the .YML file you can add an `AzureFileCopy` task to copy on the selected VM. For example you can have two or three tasks depending on your copy needs.

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/folder2'
    azureSubscription: 'subscription'
    Destination: 'AzureVMs'
    storage: 'rmstaccount'
    resourceGroup: 'rg'
    MachineNames: 'vmName'
    vmsAdminUserName: 'username'
    vmsAdminPassword: 'password'
    TargetPath: 'destinationFolder'
    skipCACheck: false
```

Azure File Copy arguments:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops